# Notification for more visits than yesterday

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to setup a notification to occur when:

The current amount of Users, today is greater than that of the previous day's.

For instance.. If yesterday shows as having 500 users and today, at 5 o'clock PM, there are 501 users...  Is there anyway to send out a single notification as soon as the threshold is broken... and not for every single new user after that threshold?

Comment: @CV, I meant to explicitly say that I wasn't using the API, but rather the interface.  I can't believe I overlooked an option in a dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing would be a custom alert (via intelligence events->custom alerts or admin->tools and assets->custom alerts).

[image]

If you set this up as a daily alert it will be sent only once per day. I have never tested this with absolute numbers (only with "increases by %" as condition), but since the option is offered in the interface I guess it should work.

Comment: You know, I got to that page and must have been in such a hurry that I didn't notice those extra options under Condition. D'oh!  Thanks.